# Direction of effect in ANOVA

Tags: anova, linear-model

Let us assume that I measure a change in something and a few factors that I believe influence this change. For example, I might measure the depth of water in a couple of buckets in the morning and in the evening and calculate the difference in depths as well as register the amount of rain and sunshine and dogs nearby:

```
         Depth.Difference Rain Sun Dogs
Bucket 1                1    4   3    7 <- more water in bucket
Bucket 2                0    2   7    0 <- no change
Bucket 3               -1    1   9    7 <- less water
....
```

Now I perform a regression analysis to see which factors have a significant effect on that change: `lm(depth.diff ~ rain + sun + dogs)`. I might get something like this:

```
            Estimate Std.Err. p-value
(Intercept)     -0.3      0.1    .344
Rain             1.4      0.2    .002 **
Sun             -2.7      0.3    .003 **
Dogs             0.5      1.7    .879
```

I made all these numbers up, but let us assume that is what I got.

**How do I know which factor had a postive and which a negative effect on the change**, i.e. which factor *increased* the water level and which factor *decreased* the water?

Can I tell that from the sign of the "Estimate"?

Comment: Be careful about using *causal* language. Note that even if the variables are causal, omitting some other variable can potentially flip the direction of the estimates (Simpson's paradox and friends), so if there's some important variables not in the model (maybe one you haven't even thought of), you may not have the correct signs on the coefficients.

Comment: @Glen_b How would you answer my question under the assumption that I had included all relevant variables in my model?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parameter estimates show that an increase in Rain (estimate=1.4) is associated with increased water level and a decrease in Sun (estimate=-2.7) is also associated with increased water level.

Comment: You mean that the negative estimate for sun does **not** mean a **de**crease? That is, both negative and positive estimates mean an increase?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think about the coefficients as slopes of a regression line (y=intercept + coefficient(x)). For the Sun predictor the slope of the regression line is negative meaning that as the dependent variable (change in depth) increases, the amount of Sun decreases. The slope for Rain is positive.